# You will find it difficult to explain of your use of such offensive language

Tags: gerunds, possessive-pronouns

> You will find it difficult/  to explain ***of* your use** / of such offensive
>   language

as per **possessive** word rule,

After "your" instead of *use* , using should come. Few example *`my going, his coming`*, so it should be *your using.* instead of your use.

But in book it says to ommit only `'of'` after explain in 2nd part.

But  my question is How **Your use** is correct. It should be Your using

Comment: I think you may have an easier time getting answers on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is confusing, the formatting, the wording. Please use *italics* or "inverted commas" to isolate words and phrases in your question.

Comment: If the book says to remove the _of_ before _such_, that’s clearly a mistake. It’s the one before _your_ that needs to go.

Comment: Pradeep, I suspect you're trying to understand why it says "your use of X" instead of "your using X". In my view either is acceptable, but "your use of X" is simpler. However, there are two problems with your question: (1) "explain *of* your use" is wrong: check you haven't added the "of" by mistake; and (2) please add exactly what the rule in your book says, as you may have misunderstood its application.

Comment: I've voted for this to be migrated to ELL, as the answer is likely to help more people on that site than on EL&U. :-)

Comment: Now i have edited question.

Comment: *Explain **of** your* is wrong. That *of* needs to be removed. The second *of* is fine. I suspect this grammatical error will distract from the actual question until it's fixed. (And migrating this to ELL will serve no useful purpose. In fact, the intended question is actually quite meaningful here.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Can we not help fix the question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not without forcing our own interpretation on it. There may be some reason for the odd phrasing that isn't clear yet. I'm not sure why the mistake is persisting, despite the comments. If I simply correct the error, leaving only the question I *think* is actually being asked, it might do more harm than good.

Comment: If you wanted to use a form of the verb *use* after *your* it would have to be *using* - this is what the rule in your book is telling you. In the sentence you quote, though, *use* is a noun (it would be pronounced with an s sound, not a z sound). Possessive + noun is fine.